# How to write unit test for functions using azure storage file share, service bus?

Tags: node.js, azure, jestjs, azureservicebus, azure-storage-files

I have nestjs application, For unit testing, I need to test getting the files data from azure storage file share, for that I'm using @azure/storage-file-share. But I dont want access the actual storage account because, in our github pipeline runner it is not accessible. Is there a way to test storage file share on local/cicd pipeline without trying to access the actual service? P.S. I'm using jest to write unit tests.

I want to do the same thing with azure service bus.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this will depend on how you have set up your app, but your best bet is mocking Storage and Service Bus. See [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-docs-en-jest-object-jestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter) for mocking a full npm module, but once you've done that, any calls to the Azure services won't actually happen, they will just do nothing and you can still test that the calls were made.

However, if your tests rely on data they pulled data from storage, I would make sure you have separated the data layer into a separate interface. For example:

```
export const loadData = (key) => {
  // use Storage library to get the file
  // ...
  return data;
}

export const saveData = (key) => {
  // use Storage library to save the file
  // ...
  return success;
}
```

If you've hidden the file implementation behind an interface like this, you can now just mock `loadData()`:

```
import * from './myDataInterface';
// ... more code ...

// 'my data' could be a string, object, whatever you need the loaded file to be to set up your test
const mock = jest.spyOn(myDataInterface, 'loadData').mockReturnValue('my data');
```

And now when the code that you are testing calls `loadData()` it will be running the mock and returning what you expected it to, not calling the storage module.

Much more about mocking in the [jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmocknamename), I wouldn't presume that this is 100% going to fit your needs but hopefully it is a good start.